# IQueryable iteration: do I need ToListAsync()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have this code

```
foreach (var e in await database.Entities.Where(...).ToListAsync())
```

As far as I understand, this code have an unneeded overhead of copying the query results into the newly created list, which I do not need. I need to just iterate over the result once, and I'm quite ok if it will remain in the EF internal structures.

On the other hand I can use this

```
foreach (var e in database.Entities.Where(...))
```

but this code will run synchronously, which can also have some unexpected performance impact.

What is the best way to get the results asynchronously, with no redundant copy?

Comment: The answer depends on many things.  How big is your database, what type of database (MS-SQL/MySql/Sqlite/Postgres) and how many records are being returned.   If the query returns less than 1000 rows, then it's unlikely to make much difference (apart from ToList using marginally more memory perhaps). Worrying about a redundant copy is extremely minor compared to things like proper indexes or faster hardware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this code have an unneeded overhead of copying the query results into the newly created list, which I do not need

Yes, but it's a list of *reference types*. It's not copying any of the entity objects themselves or anything like that, just a list of references, which is extremely fast and doesn't use up much memory.

> What is the best way to get the results asynchronously, with no redundant copy?

[Asynchronous streams](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams.md). But they're not available for EF yet. So the best way to do it *today* is `ToListAsync`.